Third data stream in files downloaded from the internet on some Win 10/11 devices but not others
We have a client using Azure Files. They raised an issue with us where trying to copy files that were downloaded from the internet into an Azure share would throw a warning re. properties being lost from the file if proceeding.
After raising with MS support, they found the files had the usual $DATA and Zone.Identifier streams, but also had a third stream named "C7140AA6-7976-4D71-9C3A-F8BD5BCEF8DD" and apparently the file system Azure runs on doesn't support that. We're desperately trying to figure out where this third stream is coming from and would really appreciate any advice!
Troubleshooting / notes.

Tested removing the stream via PowerShell, leaving the other 2, and sure enough the file copies without issue.
Tested on various machines from various organisations and found that it happens on most, but not all of the Windows 11 PC's we've tested on.
Tested AzureAD Joined, Hybrid Joined, Domain Joined and Workgroup devices, doesn't seem to make any difference.
Tested Edge, Firefox and Chrome, including incognito / in-private modes.
Tested with users who have local admin rights vs those who don't.
Compared Windows builds.
Compared with/without our antivirus (Webroot) installed.
Compared various other things but unable to find any common denominator differentiating the devices that have the third stream vs. those that don't.
On the devices that do get the third stream, it seems to happen with every file downloaded, regardless of where they were downloaded from, what their file type is, etc.


Run procmon to determine what is adding the stream.

Hi Luke, appreciate the assistance. Any chance you could please give a bit more info as to how to do that? I'm familiar with procmon but not particularly experienced with it, so I'm not sure I understand how I would use it in this case.
Would it just be a matter of running procmon before downloading a file from one of the PC's that end up with the extra stream, then doing the same on a PC that doesn't get the extra stream, and comparing results?

Run procmon on one of the computers that generates that third stream. Add a filter to procmon for Path contains :C7140AA6-7976-4D71-9C3A-F8BD5BCEF8DD. Then download a file and see what process is adding the stream.

Hi Luke, thanks again. We've run it on a couple of file downloads now (one PDF and one DOCX) but can't seem to make any sense of the results.
I've collected some screenshots of the same file download from 1 PC that appends the stream and 1 that doesn't. Any chance you could take a look and let me know if anything stands out to you?
Link: https://maxitoffice-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/leem_maxit_com_au/EldGYdXVgZ1JoiZNQa0gTewBz6eU41nPuRehyn1SIgS_nQ?e=61Xmfi

This is almost surely some file system filter driver. On a machine that generates the extra stream, try running the following commands as admin: fltmc filters and fltmc instances.

Hi Luke, really appreciate all the assistance! I ran those commands on both PCs again and compared. The "extra stream" PC had 1 extra filter, UCPD, which I found a way to disable. After rebooting and re-running the commands and confirming UCPD was no longer loaded, I tested again, but no change. I also disabled Bitlocker entirely as another test, no change.
I've added a TXT file into each directory in my OneDrive folder with the output from each machine. If you're able to please take a look and let me know if anything stands out, would be much appreciated once again!

In my experience things like this are almost always due to antivirus software. You can test this relatively easily by disabling the relevant filter drivers. You say it happens even on computers without antivirus installed. Can you run the fltmc commands on one of those computers?

Hi Luke, my apologies, I had ruled out cause the stream didn't appear either before or after installing Webroot on my PC, nor did it appear on my colleague's laptop which has Webroot installed, but after uninstalling Webroot on our test device (that usually DOES append the extra stream), the stream disappeared. So it looks like that was actually it after all. The weird thing is, the version of Webroot is the same on all 3 of the mentioned PC's, as is the Webroot policy, so figuring out what's different is the next challenge. Thanks again for all your assistance mate!
